# Can a spoof and a dark comedy be the same?

Tags: idioms

I and a group of friends were watching a video on TV when one idiot from the group (who wasn't my friend but a friend's friend) wanting to sound intellectual claimed that the video was based on "dark humour". The rest of us downright disagreed and said that the video was a spoof or a satire but could never be dark comedy. This idiot not wanting to give up then claimed that the video was both a spoof and a dark comedy. We did not argue with him further on this as there as no point. But what piqued my curiosity was that could a film/video or a work of literature be both a dark comedy and a spoof? By the way I am not a native English speaker but have taken every care to write in proper English and I would appreciate it if you could correct any errors I've made and also answer my question.

Comment: **Yes.** For example, Kubrik's *Dr. Strangelove* is a extremely well-known black comedy which employs a significant amount of satire (or a *satire* which employs a significant amount of *black humor*). For example, here's an academic  review of the film which ascribes both qualities to "*At its purest, Strangelove is a **black and satirical** comedy about ...*": http://iml.jou.ufl.edu/projects/fall11/wyzan_a/strangelove.html

Comment: I see no fundamental reason that would prelude someone doing a spoof in the style of a dark comedy.

Comment: You wrapped that up, Dan!

Comment: Oh, no. @mgb did, with the Ur-example: Swift's *A Modest Proposal*!

Comment: I think the meanings of *spoof* and *dark/black comedy/humour* are General Reference (and have effectively unrelated meanings). Any given comedy may reasonably be described using either, both, or neither terms, depending on exactly what kind of comedy it actually is.

Comment: LOL true, *modest proposal* was great thinking below

Comment: Super, a very dark spoof of Superhero movies.

Comment: Why has my question been given a negative vote?

Answer (score 5):

The British TV show *[Brass Eye](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brass_Eye)* is a dark comedy that spoofed government/media hysteria about paedophilia and drugs. Similar, though less dark, are the *The Day Today* and *The Office*.

If you want to be more literary: Swift's *[A Modest Proposal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Modest_Proposal)*

Comment: But I forgot Dr Strangelove ! Although sometimes it seems that America  is actually a spoof of Dr Strangelove

Comment: @mgb we were watching a video in my native language which was a satire on our country's existing "art" film industry. The video showed some dark scenes from art films, based on the noir genre but in a comical way. Could this be considered as dark comedy?

Comment: @user31225707, Wikipedia literally *defines* black comedy as a subgenre of satire (which makes sense, given its cynical bent). In regards to your *specific* film, does any professional (or at least well-regarded) critic or site (imdb.com, metacritic, Rotten Tomatoes, etc) mention an element of black humor? Does the following description apply, in any way? "*Topics and events that are usually regarded as taboo, specifically those related to death, are treated in an unusually humorous or satirical manner while retaining their seriousness*"

Comment: Monty Python was almost totally satire and often bc.